# Drawing full screen chessboard pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm working in **OpenCV** (camera calibration and then creating 3d model) and till now I always printed a checkerboard pattern on paper and then took pictures needed for calibration. I tried to find a way to draw the pattern on the full screen with pre-defined square sizes (so I could set that square size in the calibration process), but I only found the Python turtle module which seems to only be for drawing on part of screen, and it always draws an arrow on last square. I need to draw the pattern with some small offset from the screen borders and, inside those offsets, draw a checkerboard with uniform squares. Also, I saw some people are drawing patterns in GIMP, but not on the full screen.

OpenCV has the function `drawChessboardCorners` but it requires founded corners from previous imported images, which need to be calibrated, so I think it doesn't make sense.

If anybody has an idea how to solve this problem, either with some program or module in some programming language (Python if possible), I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I only found turtle module which seems to be only for drawing on part
>   of screen and it always draws arrow on last square.

Let's dispense with these two issues by drawing a grid in a window the size of the screen with no arrow on the last square:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

BLOCK_SIZE = 72  # pixels
CURSOR_SIZE = 20  # pixels

BORDER = 1  # blocks

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1.0, 1.0)  # display size window
width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, width, height)

block = Turtle('square', visible=False)  # hide the cursor completely
block.pencolor('black')
block.shapesize(BLOCK_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
block.penup()

x_count = width // BLOCK_SIZE - BORDER * 2
x_width = x_count * BLOCK_SIZE
x_start = (width - x_width) // 2
x_limit = x_width + (BORDER + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE

y_count = height // BLOCK_SIZE - BORDER * 2
y_height = y_count * BLOCK_SIZE
y_start = (height - y_height) // 2
y_limit = y_height + (BORDER + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE

screen.tracer(False)

for parity_y, y in enumerate(range(y_start, y_limit, BLOCK_SIZE)):
    block.sety(y)

    for parity_x, x in enumerate(range(x_start, x_limit, BLOCK_SIZE)):
        block.fillcolor(['white', 'black'][(parity_y % 2) == (parity_x % 2)])
        block.setx(x)
        block.stamp()

screen.tracer(True)
screen.mainloop()
```

(Hide your dock in OS X if you want to cover even more of the screen.)

Unfortunately, this is drawing in *pixel* units which is arbitrary.  See my answer about [drawing in a standardized measure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49604303/5771269) using the pixel pitch value of your display.

Comment: Hi, I think this solution is pretty good, drawing in pixel units is okay. Only thing is that chessboard is not filled with black-white squares, it is whole white with black borders between the squares. Where would you, in your code, put the loop for filling the color? Thanks in advance. Regards

Comment: @fjube, I've slipped in some code to alternate the colors of the boxes.  See if it fits your needs now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code for generating the chessboard pattern. However, the diameter of the chessboard is in pixel unit.

```
import numpy as np

h = 6
w = 8
size = 100
checkerboard = 255.0 * np.kron([[1, 0] * (w//2), [0, 1] * (w//2)] * (h//2), np.ones((size, size)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your chessboard pattern in your favourite graphics editor, save the file onto the computer you want to use to display it for your calibration, then just display it when needed. I think you might be over-thinking the problem...